# integration about $\arcsin $ and $\arccos $

Tags: integration

To integrate $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$, we get $\arcsin(x/a)+C $

To integrate $\frac{-1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$, we get $\arccos(x/a) + C$

but what if I take out the $-1$?

So

$\displaystyle\int \frac{-1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\,dx$ =  -$\arcsin(x/a)+C $?

Because $-1$ is a constant and we can just take it out of the integral?

I am confused.

Comment: If you mean the following cut and paste from this: integrate $-1/(a^2-x^2)^{(1/2)}$, for $arches(x/a)$ do you mean $arccos (x/a)$?

Comment: I'm unsure of what "arches" means

Comment: Notice what happen if you what $c=c'+\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: It's because of the added constant at the end, arcsine and arccosine have a linear relationship to one another, that is $\arcsin(x) + \arccos(x)= \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: but is it correct?? And if you write that in an exam will you get the marks?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

$$\arcsin(x)+\arccos(x)=\pi/2 \tag 1$$

---

**SPOILER ALERT:**  Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution

> Note that we have $\arcsin(x)=\int_0^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt$ and therefore in terms of anti-derivatives, we can write $$\arcsin(x)=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx+C$$Using $(1)$, the arccosine function can be written as the anti-derivative $$\begin{align}\arccos(x)&=\pi/2-\arcsin(x)\\\\&=\pi/2 -\left(\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx+C\right)\\\\&=-\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx +C'  \end{align}$$where $C'=\pi/2-C$

Comment: but is this correct? I still don't understand...

Comment: Draw a right triangle with hypotenuse of length $1$.  Observe that the sine of on of the acute angles is equal to the cosine of the other acute angle.  And these acute angles add to $\pi/2$.  ;-))

Answer (score -1):

arcsinx + arccosx = pi/2 (some constant).
They hold a linear relationship.
So yeah, it's somehow correct.
Try solving more differential equations of first order and first degree.