# $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=\arcsin {\frac{x}{a}} + const$ - is this the correct formula?

Tags: integration

$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=\arcsin {\frac{x}{a}} + const$

I found this formula in my study book, but I can't verify it.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%28dx%29%2F%28sqrt%28a%5E2-x%5E2%29%29%3Darcsin+x%2Fa+%2B+const

Wolfram rejects this view.

Comment: Did you try to verify it by differentiating the right-hand side?

Comment: @MartinR: this is not said, but if the OP thought to recognize the derivative of the arc sine to choose the antiderivative, the check is circular.

Comment: `1/sqrt(a^2 - x^2)` ?

Comment: It turns out that the formula is correct?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1713474/integration-about-arcsin-and-arccos

Comment: @Math-fun thanks.This is a really helpful link.

Comment: you are welcome :-)

Answer (score 2):

We assume $a, x>0$.

With $x=a\sin(t)$, so that $dx=a\cos(t)\,dt$, we can write

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=\int\frac{a\,\cos(t)}{\sqrt{a^2-a^2\sin^2(t)}}dt=t+c=\arcsin\left(\frac xa\right)+c.$$

This seems to match your answer.

---

Notice that with $x=a\cos(t)$,

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=\int\frac{-a\,\sin(t)}{\sqrt{a^2-a^2\cos^2(t)}}dt=-t+c=-\arccos\left(\frac xa\right)+c.$$

But these two solutions are not contradictory. See why ?

---

Also note that Alpha prefers a third, equivalent form:

$$\arctan\left(\frac x{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

With a change of variables you get:

$$\int^t\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx=\int^t\frac{1}{|a|\sqrt{1-\big(\frac{x}{a}\big)^2}}dx=\frac{1}{|a|}\int^{\frac{t}{a}}\frac{a}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}dy=\frac{a}{|a|}[\arcsin(y)]^{\frac{t}{a}}$$
$$=\pm\arcsin\big(\frac{t}{a}\big)+C,$$

with the sign depending of the sign of $a$.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. The result makes sense from dimensional analysis. Assuming that a and x have dimensions of length, L, then the value inside the integrand would have dimensions of $L^{-1}$. Since the term is being integrated with respect to x, a length, the antiderative gains a power of length dimensionally, and this agrees with the right hand side which is indeed dimensionless. A proof can be found of this exact result through implicit differentiation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_ybAQChyjQ&t=333s